# Scroll to specific position with ng-scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scrollbar

I am using the [ng-scrollbar](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar) directive and I am wondering how I can scroll to a specific element of the container. I am trying to to alter the core functionality so I can re-download it at any point with bower.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the code I found that the rollToBottom works only for the first rebuild.